# Azure mobile services: basic read function in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I'm learning javascript and windowsazure mobile services.  As a learning lesson I created a "users" table and inserted a test user.  I'm actually using icenium to write a demo app for the ipad and andoid tablets, but I can't seem to figure out even the most basic request. So I've setup a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MNubd/5/.

It is a simple input box:

```
<input id="uFullName" type="text" />
```

and some javascript code.  I'm trying to retrieve the "name" column from the table "users" and display it in the input box:

```
alert('running');
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mtdemo.azure-mobile.net/', 'MtxOqGpaBzuPRtnkIifqCKjVDocRPY47');
usersTable = client.getTable('users');
usersTable.where({ userID: 'impretty@blockedheaded.com' }).read({
    success: function (results) {
        $('#uFullName').val(results);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        $('#uFullName').val('there was and err');
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I had no idea the success function could only be used on server scripts.  Thanks.  Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
function signInButton(e) {
    var un = $('#username');
    uName = un.val();
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mtdemo.azure-mobile.net/', 'MtxOqGpaBzuPRtnkIifqCKjVDocRPY47');    
    //alert('lookup: ' + uName);
    usersTable = client.getTable('users');    
    usersTable.where({ userID: uName })
    .read()
    .done(
        function (results) {            
            try {
                xUserName = results[0].name; //using this to trigger an exception if the login credentials don't match.
                xUserID = results[0].id; // save this for querying and adding records for this user only.
                //alert('found');
                app.application.navigate('#view-menu');                        
            }
            catch(err) {
                 //alert('not found');
                 document.getElementById('errorText').textContent = "Check Email and Password!";                 
            }            
        } 
    );//end of the done
```

Answer (score 0):

The options object with the `success` and `error` callback objects is only used in server-side scripts. For the client side, the programming model is based on promises, and you should use the `done()` (or `then()`) continuation to get the results:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mtdemo.azure-mobile.net/', 'YOUR-KEY');
var usersTable = client.getTable('users');
usersTable.where({ userID: 'impretty@blockheaded.com' }).read().done(function (result) {
    $("#uFullName").val(result.name);
}, function (err) {
    $("#uFullName").val('There was an error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!  The function(err) messed me up for a bit because both the result and err were both being called for some reason.  To solve that I used a try as I was checking the data.  I've modified my original post with my successful code.