# Mobile Services Client gettable('mytable').read() methods not returning anything

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, winjs, azure-mobile-services

I have been trying for hours to read the table from within azure client services with absolutely no success...

I can insert items into the table fine, but when reading from the table it doesnt even seem to do the where part, I feel like i have tried every different version of code to get this working but nothing is working for me :(

```
console.log("user_id1" + user_id1)
        notpic_pushClient.getTable("myTable").where({
            user_id: user_id1
        }).read({
            success: function (results) {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    console.log("yes exists");
                } else {
                    console.log("no doesnt exist yet");
                }
            }
        });
```

This doesnt work BUT the code below does....I am baffled...do I need something special in the read section of scripts on that table?

```
 var item = { user_id: user_id1, text: "New User Added" };
 notpic_pushClient.getTable("myTable").insert(item);
```

EDIT

I have just read another post [Azure mobile services: basic read function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392849/azure-mobile-services-basic-read-function-in-javascript) that explains success is for server side and done is for client side so tried

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mydemo.azure-mobile.net/', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');   
usersTable = client.getTable("myTable");    
usersTable.where({ user_id: user_id1 })
.read()
.done(
    function (results) {
         console.log("results: " + results)            
        try {
            console.log("exists")                        
        }
        catch(err) {
              console.log("doesnt exist yet")  
        }            
    } 
);
```

BUT this still wont work, nothing gets logged to the console, I am using visual studio and dont even know if it is sending the request?

Answer (score 0):

In the client side, it's possible that there is an error returned in the `done` promise, but you're not doing anything with it. Try rewriting your code as shown below, and if there are errors you'll see them.

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mydemo.azure-mobile.net/', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');   
usersTable = client.getTable("myTable");    
usersTable.where({ user_id: user_id1 })
.read()
.done(
    function (results) {
        console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Errors: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I have also tried this and nothing is logged in the console, I have added breakpoints at both of the console logs and its as if it never goes through that part of the code :(

Comment: What kind of client application are you creating? A Windows Store app using JS, or a regular HTML/JS application?

Comment: A Windows Store/phone 8.1 app using JS

Comment: I dont know if this could be the issue, looks ok to me but on the server side the read script for the table is 

function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute();
}

Comment: I also read that the version of MobileServices.js may affect it so tried the latest web version but I still had the same problem! The code we have definitely works as when we run it through php from our server the push notifications are sent but from the app nothing seems to happen, no errors it just seems to skip to the next lines of code... the weirdest thing is that insert works PERFECTLY!

Comment: That really is strange. If you run your app with a networking capture tool such as Fiddler running, do you see any outgoing requests for the read operation in the usersTable? What about for the insert operation (which works)?